# Fire routed event when tooltip is changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add routed event to existed tooltip in control - now it is bound to simple get/set property.

binding in xaml:

```
 <Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="{x:Type myControl}">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
```

prop in myControl:

```
 public string Name
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

routed event in Control Class that contains list of myControls (I suppose I have wrote it in the right way)

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent TooltipChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ToolTipChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<string>), typeof(Control));
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<string> ToolTipChanged
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(TooltipChangedEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(TooltipChangedEvent, value);
        }
    }
```

the question is how to fire this event when tooltip is changed?

Comment: In Name setter execute Event.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? I am new in c# events really. There two question here - Need I to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in myControl class? (It was not here) and second - how to fire this event EVERY time the tooltip text is changed?

Comment: Tooltip changes you mean Name property changes?

Comment: yes. It bound the  way I have wrote but I have never reach the get/set in debug (no I notify prop changes) - There is simple hash where name is a key and value is other string - this hash initialized beforehand. And then myControl showing proper Name as tooltip. But I need to notify myself about the change of the tooltip text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MainViewModel : FrameworkElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TooltipChangedEvent));
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent TooltipChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ToolTipChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<string>), typeof(Control));
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<string> ToolTipChanged
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(TooltipChangedEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(TooltipChangedEvent, value);
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```